# Wordpress Query wpdb->get_row

Tags: php, wordpress

**I have code like this using WordPress:**

```
function an_max_form($id,$maxList)
{
  global $wpdb;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "maxform_r";
  $maxrow = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT id,maxlist FROM %s", $table_name ) );

  echo '
    <form action="' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . (isset( $_POST['id'] ) ? $id : $maxrow->id ) . '" />
        <div>
            <label for="maxList">Maximum List</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="maxList" value="' . (isset( $_POST['maxList'] ) ? $maxList : $maxrow->maxlist ) . '"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
        </div>
    </form>
  ';

}
```

This form will fetch 1 row from the database and populate it into this form. But why my form doesn't return any value. I tried to debug it using `echo $maxrow->id` but still empty. Anyone know what is wrong with my coding?

Comment: Well if it doesn't return anything, then your query must be wrong...

Comment: I don't think so. I have remove $wpdb->prepare and using only get_row and it works.

Comment: I was thinking of whole `$wpdb->get_row` statement as a query. If you're not explicitly changing anything in the database I think you're pretty much safe without `prepare` method when making a query (to fetch results).